# Federated learning for custom image classification

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

i wanted to implement Federated learning for image classification, i have xray dataset of 4 different diseases and i wannted to trian them on CNN model using FL approach, the thing is that iam Tensorflow library TFF is also not working gives an error.
Can i get some resources, TQ

I tried running a tensorflow Library for federated it gives an error everytime, on colab notbeook